# Recieving Notifications

Tags: android, youtube-api

So I have this idea of an app that would get all **youtube's** *notifications* for the day and puts them all in one page and give you some functionality over them like adding to watch later and maybe not interested and some others all in one click, in addition to that i would be able to make better *notification* tiles you know the default one isn't that good and i've seen better, I thought about it for a while and I think i am going to go about it this way:

1- stop youtube itself from sending the notifications.

2- making the app get this day's uploads and listing them.

3- making the app send the noti... in a better looking tile.

4- adding the "Other functionalities".

But..., i've looked around for notification support on the **youtube** api page and found nothing useful.

Is there any api or anything that would help me in this, i am using **android studio** BTW.